# Spring Boot @Cachable ( Default Implementation ) List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have a scenario where I have two external APIs

- List of Users (/users)
- User based on ID ( /users/{id} )

The APIs are expensive operations as it's been called from a 3rd Party Service.

I want to build a cache using Spring Boot Cache

```java
@Cachable("users")
public List<Users> getUsers(){}

@Cachable("users", key="#id")
public User getUser(){}
```

I want to build a cache such that when we call `getUsers()` the first time it will build a cache for subsequent `getUser(1)` methods.

How can I achieve this using Spring Boot ( Default implementation of Cache )?

I already tried to do the below:

```java
@Cachable("users")
public List<Users> getUsers(){}

@Cachable("users", key="#id")
public User getUser(){}
```

It creates different keys in the cache so even though I have called `getUsers()` the `getUser()` method calls the API.

Comment: You cannot as both datastructures that are being stored are different.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get it ?

Comment: It caches the results of the method as is. So a full `List` of users and a single user. It doesn't store the individual users.

Comment: In that case what should be a good design - when we want to cache all entries using one getAll method?

Comment: YOu would need to do programmatical caching, which is generally a bad idea. Depending on which data access technology you are using (assuming JPA) look into the integration possibilities of your data access technology and don't shoehorn Spring Cache into that.